# Call a field/table in a DoCmd

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to use a field (`DropPath`) found in `SetupExp` table to be referenced in a `DoCmd.OutPutTo`

```
droppath.SetupExp = D:\Export\
```

This works

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "CustItemExp", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "D:\Export\CustItemExp" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".xls", False, "", 0, acExportQualityPrint
```

This does not:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "CustItemExp", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "droppath.SetupExp" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".xls", False, "", 0, acExportQualityPrint
```

It should look at the `droppath.SetupExp` to create a CSV file called `CustItemExp.csv` in that location.

Comment: Cannot directly refer to table that way. Note for future - table name should prefix field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference table or query field values directly in VBA in the same way as you might the properties of objects on forms or reports.

Instead you'll need to acquire the value of a record within your table either using a domain aggregate function such as [`DLookup`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) or [`DFirst`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DFirst-DLast-Functions-ADB06169-BF49-4F80-BF04-1E4B5A48A8A7), or by [opening a recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/move-through-a-dao-recordset) of the table records and retrieving the value.

Based on your examples, I might suggest something along the lines of:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "CustItemExp", acFormatXLS, DFirst("droppath", "setupexp") & "CustItemExp" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".xls"
```